# Why udelay and ndelay is not accurate in linux kernel?

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, delay

I make a function like this

```
trace_printk("111111");
udelay(4000);
trace_printk("222222");
```

and the log shows it's 4.01 ms , it'OK

But when i call like this

```
trace_printk("111111");
ndelay(10000);
ndelay(10000);
ndelay(10000);
ndelay(10000);
....
....//totally 400 ndelay calls
trace_printk("222222");
```

the log will shows 4.7 ms. It's not acceptable.
Why the error of ndelay is so huge like this?

Look deep in the kernel code i found the implemention of this two functions

```
void __udelay(unsigned long usecs)
{
    __const_udelay(usecs * 0x10C7UL); /* 2**32 / 1000000 (rounded up) */
}

void __ndelay(unsigned long nsecs)
{
    __const_udelay(nsecs * 0x5UL); /* 2**32 / 1000000000 (rounded up) */
}
```

I thought udelay will be 1000 times than ndelay, but it's not, why?

Comment: Because another process is executing when the delay is over, and it needs to finish it's time slice first.

Comment: I disabled interrupt, it has nothing to do with scheduling. And this delay compare to cpu circles, even the process sleep, it won't affect the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already noticed, the nanosecond delay implementation is quite a coarse approximation compared to the millisecond delay, because of the `0x5` constant factor used. `0x10c7 / 0x5` is approximately 859. Using `0x4` would be closer to 1000 (approximately 1073).

However, using 0x4 would cause the `ndelay` to be *less than* the number of nanoseconds requested. In general, delay functions aim to provide a delay *at least* as long as requested by the user (see here: http://practicepeople.blogspot.jp/2013/08/kernel-programming-busy-waiting-delay.html).

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call it, a rounding error is added. Note the comment `2**32 / 1000000000`. That value is really ~4.29, but it was rounded up to 5. That's a pretty hefty error.

By contrast the udelay error is small: (~4294.97 versus 4295 [0x10c7]).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ktime_get_ns() to get high precision time since boot. So you can use it not only as high precision delay but also as high precision timer. There is example:

```
u64 t;
t = ktime_get_ns(); // Get current nanoseconds since boot
for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) // Send 24 1200ns-1300ns pulses via GPIO
{
    gpio_set_value(pin, 1); // Drive GPIO or do something else
    t += 1200; // Now we have absolute time of the next step
    while (ktime_get_ns() < t); // Wait for it
    gpio_set_value(pin, 0); // Do something, again
    t += 1300; // Now we have time of the next step, again
    while (ktime_get_ns() < t);  // Wait for it, again
}
```